# Does the encoding make sense in json or yaml files in python?

Tags: python, json, encoding, yaml

I've tried to save this dictionary in json or yaml file:

```py
d = {'name': 'María Gómez', 'message': '¡Es una caña atómica!'}
with open(file, 'wt', encoding='iso8859-1') as file:
   json.dump(d, file)
```

However, the file content is not in that encoding and the non-ascii characters are escaped within json or yaml files. Therefore, I assume that the encoding file doesn't make sense. Or is there some languages or characters that the encoding could make sense with this type of files?

Comment: *Better explicit then implicit*. Not all encodings are ASCII based, so it is better to have explicitly an encoding (you may use "ascii" to make it more explicit). I do not remember any system where python uses a non-ascii based encoding as default, but Windows internally uses UTF16, and a program may interface with such API (not the default API), so explicit beats implicit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import json
d = {'name': 'María Gómez', 'message': '¡Es una caña atómica!'}
json.dumps(d)
# '{"name": "Mar\\u00eda G\\u00f3mez", "message": "\\u00a1Es una ca\\u00f1a at\\u00f3mica!"}'
json.dumps(d, ensure_ascii=False)
# '{"name": "María Gómez", "message": "¡Es una caña atómica!"}'
```

**Explanation** (valid for `json.dumps` as well as for `json.dump`): [JSON encoder and decoder basic usage](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/json.html#basic-usage):

> If `ensure_ascii` is true (the default), the output is guaranteed to
> have all incoming non-ASCII characters escaped. If `ensure_ascii` is
> false, these characters will be output as-is.

Read [Character Encodings](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/json.html#character-encodings) as well.